# TfidfVectorizer and sublinear_tf scaling for feature extraction in Azure ML

Tags: python, r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am working on a ML document classification problem. Does anyone know how to n-gram Tfidf feature extraction and sublinear_tf scaling in Azure ML.

In the past I did this inSci-Kit learn using the TfidfVectorizer (see example below) but the problem is that in AzureML I cannot explicitly define my own methods or classes using a python module and would rather not upload zipped code.

I am a python person but am open to using R if there is an equivalent. There is  an R sample in the marketplace but it is dependent on unigrams.

```
TfidfVectorizer(max_df=.67,min_df=.015,lowercase=False ,sublinear_tf=True,norm='l2',tokenizer=AbstractTokenizer())
```

Best,
-Ari

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to using AzureML.

For your problem of defining own methods, AzureML is a visual Flow-based Programming Tools for ML Modeling. It's different from programming at localhost. You can define modules for different dataset process, and link them by draging and droping line linked between two modules. There is a list of existing modules on ML Stduio, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn906033.aspx. You just need to combine them to make your own ML Model.

For the problem of using Python Module, there are some limits for Python on AzureML. You can't costomize Python installation, refer to the 4th item of https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts/#limitations.

However, for R language, you can import packages that are not already installed in ML Studio. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-extend-your-experiment-with-r/#importing-packages.

Meanwhile, you also can author custom R modules in AzureML. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-extend-your-experiment-with-r/#importing-packages.

So I think you can run the R sample by installing the dependency "unigrams" thur the API `install.packages('<pkgs.zip>', ...)`.

Best Regards.